# KVO produces error/not receiving notification

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

I have a class (call it classA) that contains a property named `info` (a model class, containing lots of info), wich in turn contains a property named `name` (a string). I want another class (classB) to receive a KVO notification when the string `name` changes in classA.

This is what I'm doing now on classB:

```
[classA addObserver: self forKeyPath: @"info.name" options: 0 context: nil];
```

There are two ways the value `name` changes on classA: when it is set directly like `classA.info.name = ...` and when `info` is set like `classA.info = ...`

When `name` is changed directly KVO works perfectly. However, when the `info` property is set and `name` changes indirectly, I get this error:

```
Cannot update for observer <classB> for the key path "info.name" from <classA>, most likely because the value for the key "info" has changed without an appropriate KVO notification being sent. Check the KVO-compliance of the classA class.
```

What should I change on classA to make this work?

Comment: Did you implement this model class and if so do you call `willChangeValueForKey:` before and `didChangeValueForKey:` after changing a property?

Comment: @trojanfoe `name` is set directly by a view-based tableview, using bindings, so there I can't do anything. `info` is set by me, and I'm not doing that. I've tried what you said just now and it still doesn't work. Same error. Oh, and by the way, I created this model class (classA)

Comment: Show the code you are using to update the `name` property.

Comment: @trojanfoe `name` is bound to a textfield in a tableview. Perhaps you mean the code to change the `info` property? Here: `[classA setInfo: newInfo]` It's kinda what you'd expect.

Comment: And you call `will/didChangeValueForKey:@"info.name"` before and after that?

Comment: @trojanfoe I customized that setter for other stuff, so I call will/didChangeValueForKey inside that setter before/after changing the ivar `item` of classA.

Comment: I think you need to generate the `will/didChange..` notifications for all the possible things that might have changed in the `info`, including the `name` property.

Comment: @trojanfoe Nevermind this question. I ended up solving this problem using another approach.

Comment: @Alex what approach did you end up using to solve this?

Comment: @mohabitar I, hmm, modified a small bit of funtionality on my program so that I didn't have to do any of this at all. I realise that might not be very helpful to you, sorry...

Answer (score 4):

The cause of this issue comes from the fact that you are implementing the setter `-setInfo:` for info and calling `willChangeValueForKey:` | `didChangeValueForKey:` inside it.

I've seen many instances in which it is believed that the `will|didChange...` calls need to be implemented for the KVO notification to be fired.  This is true only when the setter is not explicitly called.  When you do call the setter, the KVO mechanism takes care of firing the notification.

Most of the times leaving these calls in the setter is harmless and just causes extra notifications, but as seen in this case, it does cause a problem when updating a keypath -- as opposed to a key.

In short, if you do implement a setter, do not call `will|didChangeValueForKey:` inside of it.

Comment: This was the right answer for my case. I have a sea of bindings, some of them connected via paths, not just keys. Commenting out the will|didChange... calls inside the setter did the trick!

Answer (score -1):

Options cannot be 0, I think.

Its an old API, back before Apple got diligent about API design, and you have to give it *something*.

Comment: According to the docs: `NSKeyValueObservingOptions
These constants are passed to addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context: and determine the values that are returned as part of the change dictionary passed to an observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:. You can pass 0 if you require no change dictionary values.`

Comment: Thanks. I guess it was an old bug then? - I've previously had KVO start working after changing options from 0 to ... any ... of the bitmask options.

Comment: It has always been fine. Maybe delete this answer?